# Closing a dialog when a new one gets opened in Vaadin

Tags: vaadin

I created a dialog in a certain UI.

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
dia.add(new TestView());
dia.open();
```

The new UI TestView contains a button that again creates a new dialog

```
private void button_onClick(ClickEvent<Button> event {
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
    dia.add(new TestView2());
    dia.open();
    ...
}
```

How do i close the first dialog when the second gets created?

`((Dialog)this.getParent()).close();` is not possible.

For better understanding:
[image]

When UiTwo creates UiThree, i want UiTwo to be closed. So that there is always only one dialog opened.

Comment: You can save a reference of your currently used dialog in a field and close it when reassigning (opening a new dialog) it

Comment: @JuliusHörger can you give an example how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is actually possible with your approach, but note that `getParen()` returns an `Optional<Component>`, not a `Component`. As such, you must do something like this:

```
getParent().ifPresent(parent -> {
    if (parent instanceof Dialog) {
        ((Dialog) parent).close();
    }
});
```

Or if you are brave

```
((Dialog) getParent().get()).close();
```

If you want to do it the reference way, this is one way:

```
@Route
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {

    public MainView() {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
        dialog.add(new DialogView(dialog));
        dialog.open();
    }
}
```

And your `TestView2`

```
public class DialogView extends VerticalLayout {

    public DialogView(Dialog dialog) {
        Button button = new Button("Next step");
        button.addClickListener(e -> {
            dialog.close();
            Dialog newDialog = new Dialog();
            newDialog.add(new Span("You are in the third step"));
            newDialog.open();
        });
        add(button);
    }
}
```

You don't even have to close the first dialog, you can just replace the contents

```
public class DialogView extends VerticalLayout {

    public DialogView(Dialog dialog) {
        Button button = new Button("Next step");
        button.addClickListener(e -> {
            dialog.removeAll();
            dialog.add(new Span("You are in the third step"));
        });
        add(button);
    }
}
```

If you have many views that you want to cycle through like this, I would make an abstract class that implements the common functionality between all views.

Answer (score 1):

This could work for you:

```java
    public static class CustomDialog extends Dialog {

        private Dialog parent;

        public CustomDialog(Dialog parent) {
            this.parent = parent;
        }

        @Override
        public void open() {
            super.open();
            if (parent != null) {
                parent.close();
            }
        }
    }
    // Usage:
    public MainView() {

        CustomDialog parentDialog = new CustomDialog(null);
        parentDialog.add(new Button("Open child", e-> {
            CustomDialog childDialog = new CustomDialog(parentDialog);
            // set some content to child dialog
            childDialog.open();
        }));
        parentDialog.open();
        //...
```

Comment: Isn't there a direct way to access the dialog that was created in the UI "above" in order to close it?

Comment: Dialogs aren't aware of other Dialogs by default. That example provides a way of doing exactly that.

Comment: My main UI is no dialog. There is only one dialog where i want to get my attributes from.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but at least my idea would be just to use normal Java programming techniques like above to pass information between objects.